# View does not show ViewModel property changes after async operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, mvvmcross

My ViewModel has a 30 second data refresh service delegate method:

```
public Task OnDataRefreshed(List<MyType> data)
{
    this.Data = data;
    LongRunningGetDetailsAsync();
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Public property `Data` is displayed and refreshed in the view properly.

The intention here is not to await the async task (fire-and-forget) `LongRunningGetDetailsAsync()` as it will introduce a significant delay before the `Data` is displayed if executed sync. I want to show `Data` ASAP and then let async task fetch the details at its own pace and let the view binding catch up then.

```
private async Task LongRunningGetDetailsAsync()
{
    foreach (MyType dataitem in this.Data)
    {
        dataitem.Details = await _apiEndpointService.GetDetails(dataitem.Id);
    }
}
```

`LongRunningGetDetailsAsync()` is where the binding is not firing. I set a break point at the end of `LongRunningGetDetailsAsync` watching Data.Details - the Data.Details are there, but it is never displayed in the view.

Thank you in advance for your time!

**EDIT:**
Changed to

```
public async Task OnDataRefreshed(ObservableCollection<MyType> data)
{
    this.Data = data;
    await LongRunningGetDetailsAsync();
}
```

- still have the same issue. `Data` is bound to `Mvx.MvxListView`. If the list is long and an item happens to be out of view, once scrolled to, it displays the updated model OK.

"Data":

```
    public class MyType
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyType> _data;
    public ObservableCollection<MyType> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _data, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
            }
        }
    }
```

View binding:

```
        <Mvx.MvxListView
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Data"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem" 
        ... />
```

listitem:

```
       <TextView local:MvxBind="Text MyProperty" ...
       <TextView local:MvxBind="Text Details" ...
```

Comment: Are you using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface? How does the property `Details` look like?

Comment: @Default Details is primitive - please see the edit above

Comment: You need to fire PropertyChanged when it changes. Could you also add how you bind it in your view?

Comment: @Default `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);` on `set`, View - please see the addition above

Comment: yes, well, you need it on the `Details` property - that is the one changing. Your `Data` doesn't (in the call `Details = ..`). Also, try to avoid setters for your collections. If you need to add new data then use `Clear` and `Add[Range]` instead.

Comment: @Default In the current implementation (still not working) I run `LongRunningGetDetailsAsync` on a `.ToList()` copy and then assign it back to the collection `Data = list`

Comment: Ok. Kind of hard for me to figure out since that is not the code you are showing. Add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

First, use `await` keyword when you're calling your function and mark your function as `async`.

```
public async Task OnDataRefreshed(List<MyType> data)
{
    this.Data = data;
    await LongRunningGetDetailsAsync();
}
```

Now as I understand, you want to show items in your UI as soon as you get each of them. If your bindings are correct, the changes above should do what you need. You should probably use `ObservableCollection<>` instead of `List<>` for `Data` property though.

Comment: Thanks Alireza. I did change my Task to async/await LongRunning... My problems might have something to do with `MvxListView` and how it handles the data binding. When list items are scrolled out of the view, and then back in, the values do appear as expected. If the list is too short and there is no scroll - no UI updates.

Comment: Have you changed `List<>` to `ObservableCollection<>`? What you're describing is what people encounter when binding to a `List<>` instead of `ObservableCollection<>`

Comment: Yes, I have my list set up as ObservableCollection now to no effect. My thought is that it has something to do with the fact that the model update is performed asynchronously. I tried a couple things: `RequestMainThreadAction` and `InvokeOnMainThread` but that did not help either. Not sure whee to take it from here. @Stuart @Martijn00 any pointers?

Comment: OP is changing properties on the _items_, not the list itself. Although I agree that ObservableCollection (or ICollectionView) would be more suitable here, I doubt that it would solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're changing the `Details` property you need to let the view know that it has changed. You would need to use the same logic as you do for your `Data` property:

```
private string _details;
public string Details
{
    get { return _details; }
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref _details, value))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Details);
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, try to avoid setters for your lists. In the future you may have other logic connected to your lists which, when overwritten, just complicates things. Instead, since it is exposed as an `ObservableCollection<T>` you can call `Clear` and then `Add` on the value from the getter.